# Which JSON.Net Libary have to used with Mono for Android 4.x

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, json.net

I have to deserialize a complex JSON (as Request result from a Webservice).

I try to use the Onboard JSON and simple JSON but don't get the wanted result.

Now I wanna try Json.Net, but as newbie in Json and json.net I am not sure which libary I have to use (using Xamarin Studio 4.0.8, and the target Android Version is 4.0).

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the one from the `Components` Store.

There's a folder named `Components`. DoubleClick on it, Get More Components, and install it.

That's the easiest way to get a working version.